# iOS file chooser for iCloud drive can't find tags

Tags: icloud, ios, finder-tag

Any iOS app can let its users pick a file on iCloud Drive with the proper chooser dialogue. This dialogue allows to search files based on tags. Here is a screenshot to make crystal clear what I am discussing here:

[image]

So some files on my iCloud drive have tags, which I added using the Finder on my mac running Yosemite. Typing the tag in the search box above results in an empty list: no file is found.

This is in direct contrast with the Finder on MacOS where search tags does work as exemplified by the following two screenshots:

[image]

and then

[image]

I would appreciate if somebody else could either confirm the problem, or on the contrary find that searching by tags works fine. I tested on an iPad Air running iOS 8.3 which is the most recent version at the time of writing.

Note that Keynote and Pages use this file chooser, to pick images e.g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finder tags are specific to OS X.

I'm almost certain the "tags" tab in the iCloud Drive picker does nothing right now. Tapping on it in Pages on iPhone 6 simply rearranged the folders, and I don't have any tags assigned to any files in Drive (either on OS X or elsewhere - all I have in Drive is the example iWork documents).

Even if it did do anything, I don't think it would do what you're thinking - that's a tab bar, meaning you select one of the choices. It's for sorting the presented list of files/folders, given that it contains Name and Date as well.

I also can't find anything on tags in relation to iCloud Drive, even for developers.

Comment: Thanks. That still leaves the question about what is searched. At the moment, clearly only the file name in my setup.

Answer (score 0):

Im running iOS 9 and having the exact same issue. Not only does it as far as I can tell not reliably sort my files by their tags but when I try to search specific tags and filter the results that way it also doesn't work the way it does on the Mac as you've shown. They seem to have missed this feature and I can only hope they will improve the likeness of iCloud Drive for iOS to the Mac OS Finder, in iOS 10.

Hope this confirmation of the issue helps.